# Getting index of elements in a series object looking up from another series object

Tags: python, list, indexing

Here, series2 is a always a subset of series1. I want to find the indices from series1 for the elements that are present in series2.

```
series1= [11,22,3,4,5,33,7]
series2= [11,22,33]


c=[]
for i in series2:
    if i in series1:
        c.append(series1.index[i])
print(c)
```

Expected output: [0,1,5]
But i am getting a blank list in output. Could you suggest the mistake here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension with `enumerate`, defining `series2` as a `set` to reduce the lookup complexity:

```
series2= set([11,22,33])
[ix for ix,i in enumerate(series1) if i in series2]
# [0, 1, 5]
```

---

As per your approach, there are a couple of things wrong:

- You should be iterating first over `series1` and *then* `series2`
- `list.index` if a function, it't not subscribable. You should be using `list.index(item)`

I'd suggest you to check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) on data structures to get a more clear understanding on these points

Answer (score 0):

you need to change c.append(series1.index[i]) to c.append(series1.index(i))

```
In [3]: series1= [11,22,3,4,5,33,7]
   ...: series2= [11,22,33]
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: c=[]
   ...: for i in series2:
   ...:     if i in series1:
   ...:         c.append(series1.index(i))
   ...: print(c)
[0, 1, 5]
```